# Regular expressions ,php, "AND"

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to search for three pieces of data from a string and they are:

```
first name, space ,last name  (?=[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+) 
//AND
first name ,space ,last name ,and suffix (?=[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+) 
//AND,
age   (?=[0-9]{2})
```

from several tutorials I've seen it seems that these three patterns:

```
(?=[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+)(?=[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+)(?=[0-9]{2})
```

together should be my solution, but its not working.... any suggestions....(its a php script and im using preg_match_all)

my script:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.somesite.com');
$pattern = '/(?=[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+)(?=[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+)(?=[0-9]{2}) /';
if(preg_match_all($pattern,$content,$matches))
{
// has the pattern, do something
//$matches has all the matches from preg_match

  }
```

Comment: Please post your script

Comment: The string "its [sic] not working" is not a built-in error message in PHP.

Comment: Ive posted my script...i am not getting an error in my error console...

Answer (score 1):

That multiple-lookahead trick is for times when you know certain components must be present, but you don't know what order they'll appear in.  You see it most often in regexes that enforce strong password policies.

Your problem is much simpler; the components always come in the same order, but the last one is optional.  That's much easier:

```
'/\b([A-Z][a-z]*)\s+([A-Z][a-z]*)(?:\s+([0-9]{2}))?\b/'
```

The first name is captured in group #1, the last name will be in group #2, and if there's a suffix you'll find it in group #3.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an OR operator, not an AND:

```
[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+|[0-9]{2}
```

If there can be multiple space characters between words, make sure to quantify the `\s`:

```
[A-Z][a-z]+\s+[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+\s+[A-Z][a-z]+\s+[A-Z][a-z]+|[0-9]{2}
```

And don't forget about *anchors* (`^` and `$`) if you're looking for exact matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use non-capturing group `(?:...)` and question marks to make the groups optional:

```
[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s[0-9]{2,3})?)?
```

If you want to extract the data, using named captures is a clean way:

```
$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
(?<first_name>[A-Z][a-z]+)
\s+
(?<last_name>[A-Z][a-z]+)
(?:
    \s+ (?<suffix>[A-Z][a-z]+)
    (?: \s+ (?<age> [0-9]{2,3}) )?
)?
~x
LOD;

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    echo '<br/>' . $match['first_name'] . ', ' . $match['last_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
([a-zA-Z]+\s+[a-zA-Z]+\s+[a-zA-Z0-9])
```

You can test your RegEx with tools like http://www.cyber-reality.com/regexy.html